# Is there an issue with StackOverflow reputation points not being added?

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've been making a few edits to other people's questions on Stack Overflow today. I can see my edits have been accepted, but the associated reputation points have not been added.

Is there a known issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm ok for reputation points, but I don't get all the notifications...

Comment: "Lee Taylor had 525 edit suggestions approved, and 59 edit suggestions rejected" You've already earned 1000 rep from edits, that's the cap.